# List comprehension to iterate through dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have written code to encode one row of a dataframe to json, as follows:

```
def encode_df_metadata_row(df):
    return {'name': df['Title'].values[0], 'code': df['Code'].values[0], 'frequency': df['Frequency'].values[0], 'description': df['Subtitle'].values[0], 'source': df['Source'].values[0]}
```

Now I would like to encode an entire dataframe to json with some transformation, so I wrote this function:

```
def encode_metadata_list(df_metadata):
    return [encode_df_metadata_row(df_row) for index, df_row in df_metadata.iterrows()]
```

I then try to call the function using this code:

```
df_oodler_metadata = pd.read_csv('DATA\oodler-datasets-metadata.csv')
response = encode_metadata_list(df_oodler_metadata)
print(response)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I've tried a bunch of variations but I keep getting similar errors. Does someone know the right way to do this?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe first use `print()`, `print(type())` to see what you have in variables in `encode_df_metadata_row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.iterrows` yields pairs of `index` and `row`, where each `row` is a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) object. It stores a single element for each column, so the `.values[0]` part in your `encode_df_metadata_row(df)` function becomes irrelevant - the correct form of this function should be:

```
def encode_df_metadata_row(row):
    return {'name': row['Title'], 'code': row['Code'], 'frequency': row['Frequency'], 'description': row['Subtitle'], 'source': row['Source']}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to provide an answer, tyrrr. That was exactly the issue.